# how to pass custom arguments to app

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm trying to run node app with pm2 via command line and pass only one argument with it

```
pm2 start app.js --node-args="41"
pm2 start app.js --env dev --node-args="41"
```

I tried to run it with developement environment and without it but in both ways it didn't worked.

What is the way to do it?

Comment: and I saw other topics about it and still couldn't run the app..

Comment: Do you want to pass the argument to the node V8 engine, or to app.js?

Comment: to app. to be able to get it from process.argv

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pm2 command line option *--node-args* is for passing arguments to the Node.js V8 engine, not to the program running on that engine.

The correct way to pass arguments to your program is this:

```
pm2 start app.js -- 41
```

For dev environment:

```
pm2 start app.js --env dev -- 41
```

So basically, anything you add after the last two dashes is accessible through *process.argv* as an array.

Comment: and how to handle it with developement environment?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a process file at your project root and pass your `env` and `args` like this:

**process.json**

```
{
  "apps" : [
    {
      "name"               : "app-prod",
      "script"             : "app.js",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "production"
      }
    },
    {
      "name"               : "app-dev",
      "script"             : "app.js",
      "args"               : "41",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This definition will allow you to pass command line argument (41) that will only be available in your `development` version.
Then, if you want to run `development` version of your app, execute it as follows

`pm2 start process.json --only app-dev`

Comment: im looking for inline code only, i want to run it with command line and not adding new json file

Comment: Use `NODE_ENV=development pm2 start app.js -- 41` and then handle command line argument according to the value of `NODE_ENV` in your code